# Avoid column update using a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a table `Product` with columns `id`, `description` and `currentStock`. I want to avoid the update of `currentStock` using an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger.

I tried updating every other column in the trigger but I can't reference the `Inserted` pseudo table on the update sentence.

How can I do it? Is there a better of avoiding update on `currentStock` column?

```
CREATE TRIGGER T9 ON Product 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
    UPDATE Product
    SET Product.id = inserted.id???? ,
        Product.description =  inserted.description??????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If applicable you could deny update on specific column:

```
DENY UPDATE ON dbo.Product(currentStock) TO user_name;  --role name
```

Update statement cannot refer to that column, otherwise you will get error.

```
UPDATE Product
SET currentStock = ?
WHERE ...;
-- error

UPDATE Product
SET currentStock = ?
  ,description = ?
WHERE ...;
-- error

UPDATE Product
SET description = ?
WHERE ...;
-- will run successfully
```

---

And with trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T9 ON Product INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
UPDATE p
SET description = i.description
FROM Product p
JOIN inserted i
  ON p.id = i.id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea3c8257fe138af39a8418dbed1f55e2)**